# Starting wrapped jar with another parameters

Tags: java, wrapper, tanuki

I wrapped my jar with Tanuki wrapper.
The app has some default parameters but i want to start it for example like this:

java -jar myapp.jar --zk localhost:2020 --uri localhost:1919

and etc.

I thought that i need to change the config file from tanuki and i did this:

```
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=/opt/folder/lib/app.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log
wrapper.app.parameter.1=/opt/folder/lib/jar-0.1.0.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2= --uri localhost:1919
wrapper.app.parameter.3= --zk localhost:2020
```

But i can not start is now.
What can cause this problem and how can i fix this. I think it is the config file but i did not found good example of it.

This is the error:

```
Job for app.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status app.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Failed to start service app
```

> Apr 03 09:25:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting service... Apr 03 09:25:26 localhost.localdomain app[5643]:
>   Starting service... Apr 03 09:25:30
>   localhost.localdomain app[5643]: Waiting for service.....
>   . Apr 03 09:25:30 localhost.localdomain app[5643]:
>   WARNING: service may have failed to start. Apr 03
>   09:25:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: app.service: control
>   process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 03 09:25:30
>   localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start service. 
>   Apr 03 09:25:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit
>   app.service entered failed state. Apr 03 09:25:30
>   localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: app.service failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split `wrapper.app.parameter` on several lines.

```
wrapper.app.parameter.1=/opt/folder/lib/jar-0.1.0.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2=--uri 
wrapper.app.parameter.3=localhost:1919
wrapper.app.parameter.4=--zk 
wrapper.app.parameter.5=localhost:2020
```

As described here https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate-jar-nix.html - there are no spaces for `wrapper.app.parameter`

BTW, what error did you get?

Comment: `java -jar myapp.jar --zk localhost:2020 --uri localhost:1919` worked, rigth? Could you please execute "journalctl -xe" - I suppose journal should have some detailed description about error.